# Midnight Commander: working with slow devices/resources

Tags: mc

Midnight Commander (mc) may appear "hanging" too often and for quite a long time when a folder with a lot of files located on a slow device/resource like MTP device or SFTP is shown in one of its panels.

Typical problematic scenario in detail:

1. Open folder of a slow device/resource in one of the mc's panels as a source for copying files and face the long "freezing" for the first time (but ok, it is expected).
2. Choose some other folder from a quick device (e.g. local HDD) in the other panel to copy some files to, create a subfolder there facing the long "freezing" again (it looks like mc rereads the slow device/resource although nothing has changed there).
3. Execute some command via the command line (intentionally or by a mistake) and have the "freezing" one more time which is very annoying.

Note: this is not a problem of slow start of mc, it starts instantly on my PC; I use bash as the default shell.

I understand that the root case here is the slow device/resource but can the behavior be improved/tweaked somehow (e.g. less frequent rereading folder's contents)? When I perform the same scenario using two windows of other file explorer like Gnome Files, I have no such a problem.

Comment: You'd almost certainly be better off submitting a feature request to your UNIX/Linux distribution, or even upstream

Answer (score 0):

MC is **severely** lacking in funding and developer resources. Your best bet would be to sponsor this feature. Anyways, you need to ping https://midnight-commander.org

Distro maintainers are often not even programmers, there's no way they will implement this new feature.